# Need help refactoring JavaScript code to be easier to modify, maintain, and to be more robust

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The search page has lots of facets which are tracked with breadcrumbs, additional sections that can be added to narrow searches, saving of searches, result counts that update in real-time, lots of stuff. I'm using JavaScript and jQuery for all the UI stuff, and this code is basically a mash of functions and a big ol' document ready function. When a search is triggered, the criteria is gathered based on what is shown in the UI. So for example to get some of the facets, I literally just look at what crumbs are currently shown and look at their data()/text/class/etc. to determine the criteria.

What I need is help with how to organize and design my code for this type of application. I don't have one coherent question, but I'll make an attempt at a few.

- Is it an okay practice to treat a DOM element as you would an object in say, Java? For example I have a breadcrumb, which is really just a div. I have functions for creating crumbs, removing them, etc. I treat the text and data() like I would the fields of an object.
- Continuing off the previous example, I don't actually have a Crumb JavaScript object. Should I? What would be the best way to keep the association between the object and element, especially since these are constantly being created and deleted.
- Slightly tangential, but any suggestions for testing? Nothing I've done is even unit tested which really doesn't sit right with me...

TL;DR Had to build a complicated search UI as quickly as possible while learning JavaScript and it became a mess. Need help with best practices and how to organize my code.

Comment: If you have working code that you're willing to post and you want feedback on it, a good place to go is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, you have these options to take advantage of it:

1. jQuery already provides a DOM wrapper around a DOM object that provides both a wrapper and lots of methods on it.  You can use that rather than create your own wrapper object.
2. You can easily create new methods to operate on jQuery objects if that makes item 1 more practice.  jQuery plugins are not more difficult than `jQuery.myMethod = function() { code here }`.
3. If you want your own object with your own methods, then it can just contain either the relevant DOM element or relevant jQuery wrapper on your DOM element (depending upon whether you regularly need a jQuery object in order to operate on the DOM element).
4. jQuery provides `.data()` which lets you access and store properties of DOM elements in ways that persist as long as the DOM element persists, but don't cause memory leaks.  If you aren't building your own object, you can use this to store instance data associated with a DOM element.  If you are building your own object that will contain your DOM element, then you can just store properties on your own object directly.
5. It is generally better to not be storing lots of custom properties on DOM elements themselves so you should either be storing them in your own custom javascript objects or using something like jQuery's `.data()`.

More specifics about how is best to do this require thorough knowledge of exactly what you're doing, what your operations are, how the lifetime of your elements works, what instance data you need to keep track of, how you access and store or find references to these elements, etc...  There is no single answer as the appropriate architecture depends upon a lot of the requirements which you haven't disclosed other than at a very, very general level.